# Why does this execute method makes AN stop working

Tags: animation-nodes

As soon as I add the execute method, AN is gone when I start blender.

```
import bpy
from ... base_types.node import AnimationNode

class Foo(bpy.types.Node, AnimationNode):
    bl_idname = "an_Foo"
    bl_label = "Foo"


    def create(self):
        self.outputs.new("an_StringSocket", "Debug", "debug")


    def execute(self):
        debug = "foo"
        return debug
```

Its in a folder called serial where I have another node with the same problem.

Comment: Not sure, I just tested it and the node works as I expect. You should give some more details about the issue. Most importantly the error message in the console. Maybe you put the node into a wrong directory or so?

Comment: @JacquesLucke thanks for pointing out the console!

Comment: The console is pretty important when you want to develop something for blender :)  The node file should be in a subdirectory in the nodes folder. If you create a folder there yourself, don't forget to insert an empty __ init __.py file inside first. Otherwise AN won't find the node.

Answer (score 1):

It was inconsistent use of tab and spaces. I used tabs where the document was using 4 spaces before.

The console clearly report this.

Comment: Ah okay, which editor do you use? I think some editors have the option to recognize the indentation type of a file automatically so that errors like this one rarely occure. (personally I suggest to use Atom, but that's my personal preference atm)

Comment: sublime at the moment for this, but later on I might use pycharm. And I see it in sublime when I select all text.

Comment: ok, I think they are good enouph too :D